# Any way to remove/disable breakpoints for specific file(s) in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, breakpoints, visual-studio-debugging

I need to remove/disable all breakpoints for specific class file in Visual Studio, I think right now we just have option for entire solution/project from Visual Studio

Currently I need to do it manually, not sure if any way to Disable/Delete breakpoints for current/specific file instead of entire solution in Visual Studio, manually its very cumbersome process.

Comment: There is [breakpoint window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?#BKMK_Specify_advanced_properties_of_a_breakpoint_).

Comment: Goto Debug ->Windows -> Breakpoints,  Search File name and do enable/disable breakpoint for searched file